# Is it possible to extend $f$ by continuity at $z = 0$? Why or why not?

Tags: limits, continuity

Let $f(z) = \frac{z}{|x|}$, with $z \not=0$

**(a)** Construct two sequences ${u_n}$ and ${v_n}$ such that

1. $\lim_{n \to \infty} u_n = 0$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} v_n = 0$
2. $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(u_n)$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(v_n)$ exist
3. $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(u_n)\not= \lim_{n \to \infty} f(v_n)$

**(b)** Is it possible to extend $f$ by continuity at $z = 0$? Why or why not?

I have already answered to the part (a). My problem is that I am stuck to prove the part (b). I think we can't extend $f$ by continuity at $z = 0$. Is anyone is able to explain to me?

**P.S.** I need an explication without using the theorem linking limit and limit on a sequence.

Comment: For $b$ you need a stronger condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose by contradiction that $f$ can be extended by continuity at zero, and let $\lambda$ denote this value.

Since there exist $\ell\neq\ell^\prime$ such that $f(u_n)\to \ell$, $f(u_n)\to \ell^\prime$, there is at least one of the two values satisfying $\ell\neq \lambda$ or  $\ell^\prime\neq \lambda$. Without loss of generality, suppose $\ell\neq \lambda$.

Fix $\varepsilon = \frac{1}{3}\lvert \ell - \lambda \rvert > 0$.

- Since  $\lim_0 f = f(0) = \lambda$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $\lvert f(x)-\lambda\rvert \leq \varepsilon$ for any $x$ such that $\lvert x\rvert \leq \delta$.
- Since $u_n\to 0$, there exists $N_1\geq 0$ such that $\lvert u_n\rvert \leq \delta$ for any $n\geq N_1$.
- Since  $f(u_n)\to \ell$, there exists $N_2\geq 0$ such that $\lvert f(u_n)-\ell\rvert \leq \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ for any $n\geq N_2$.

Let $N_0 = \max(N_1,N_2)$. Then for $n\geq N_0$, we have *(1)* $\lvert u_n\rvert \leq \delta$, so that $\lvert f(u_n) - \lambda\rvert \leq \varepsilon$.  But we also have *(2)* $\lvert f(u_n) - \ell\rvert \leq \varepsilon$. By the triangle inequality, this implies $\lvert \lambda - \ell\rvert \leq 2\varepsilon < \lvert \lambda - \ell\rvert$, contradiction.

Comment: Note that this does not appeal to the theorem on sequential characterization of continuity: the reason is, it basically mimics (some of) the argument of its proof...

Answer (score 1):

One can show that a function $f$ is continuous at a point $z$ if and only if for any sequence $z_n$ converging to $z$ we have $f(z_n)\to f(z)$ when $n\to\infty$.

Your part (a) show that there are two sequences $u_n$ and $v_n$ converging to zero such that $f(u_n)$ and $f(v_n)$ have different limits. Hence, the function $f$ is not continuous at zero.

Added after the "P.S.": in order for $f$ to be continuous at zero, given $\epsilon$, we must find $\delta>0$ such that $|f(z)-f(0)|<\epsilon$ when $|z|<\delta$. But this is impossible since if $f(u_n)\to a$ and $f(v_n)\to b$ with $a\ne b$, then $f(0)$ would have to be both $a$ and $b$ (just take $z=u_n$ and $z=v_n$).

Comment: Please look at the P.S from the question.